# ActionBar style is not Affecting NewApi

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I am using a customized Action Bar. I am creating an app for a wide range of API level(API8-API21)

My Customized Action Bar is working in API level 9. But it is not working in API level > 11

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
</application>
```

My styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/green</item>
    <item name="background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
```

**Note:** I am not defining any style for my activities

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

But My actionbar is still as default. can somebody help me??

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself..

I need to change styles.xml in values-v11 and values-v14 too as follows

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```